# JSP - Connecting and Inserting data to MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, netbeans

Right, here's my situation, I have a form on a page (index.jsp) which submits data to a JSP page (output.jsp) which will then do things with the data and output a result. I would like to insert the results of this into a MySQL database.

I've tried doing some things with MySQL directly in the JSP but I've been advised against this as it opens security holes, I believe.

So I have created a SubmitServlet.java (by default, Netbeans has put it into Source Packages/default package, opposed to the location of the JSP files, in Web Pages). I understand that I've got to do a lot of the connecting here, though I'm not entirely sure how to get the data submitted into the database from the JSP, to the servlet. What do I need to do?

I have read several tutorials at RoseIndia, but they've only just left me more confused as to what is actually required so any help would be appriciated greatly!

PS: Also worth pointing out I am completely new to Java web applications, so the more you treat me like a complete idiot, the better!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

call the required method from output.jsp which will insert the data into the database

```
<%
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="yourPackage.className" />
String Success="";
Success=sobj.myRequiredMethod("this is my result");
%>
```

in yourPackage.className class u should have the myRequiredMethod()

```
package yourPackage;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class className
    {
    String mySqlPassword="root";
    String mySqlUsername="root";
    String mySqlDatabase="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDatabse";


ResultSet res;



    public String myRequiredMethod(String result)
        {

        String success="";
        try
            {


            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(mySqlDatabase,mySqlUsername,mySqlPassword);

                String q="insert into myTable (resultColumn) values('" + result + "')";
            System.out.println(q);
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(q);
            int pos = stmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(pos);
        if(pos==1)
                {
                    success="Successfull";
                }
            } 

        catch(Exception e)
            {
        }

        return success;

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rose India's not a good place to learn.

No, you need an intermediate servlet or two.

Break the problem into chunks: schema, CRUD operations, mid-tier models, service, marshalling HTTP requests into objects and back, HTML and CSS and JavaScript.  Don't try to do the whole thing at once.  Start with a a single vertical and make that work, then move to the next.

Decomposition is the hallmark of computer science and problem solving.

Comment: +1 "Decomposition is the hallmark of computer science and problem solving." Worth quoting!